# Entire Column green if all cells in it are empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, search, conditional-formatting

I would like all columns that only contain empty cells to light up green.

In the below picture these should be: C3:C8, D3:D8, E3:E8, L3:L8

What would be the correct custom formula for this?

---

Bonus question: I would also like columns that contain only a question mark (so no x) to show up yellow, what would be the correct formula for this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Question should include only one question per post. Also it's recommended to include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- custom formula for range **B3:O8**

  ```
  =NOT(COUNTIF(B$3:B$8, "<>"))
  ```

  [image]

---

- custom formula for range **B3:O8**

  ```
  =FIND("?",A$3&A$4&A$5&A$6&A$7&A$8)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!
Do you also happen to know how to have the column show up yellow if there is only a question mark somewhere in the column?